# How to record vertical video on Chrome Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

I have tried the following code, it works for Chrome Desktop, but not on Chrome Android, can someone help?.

```
let stream = await browserNavigator?.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    width: { min: 200, max: 400, ideal: 360 },
    height: { min: 400, max: 640, ideal: 640 },
    facingMode: "user",
    aspectRatio: 9/16,
  }
});
```